# Multistep composition using MEF in C#

Tags: c#, frameworks, mef, managed, extensibility

I have a rather complex application which is initialized in multiple steps or phases. Some components are created during construction, some when user context is available, some when frond end gets available. I want to use MEF to create an easy extensible initialization process.

My question now... is is possible to have a MEF compose in multiple steps? Some imports can be satisfied, but some others only after e.g. user context is available within second composition.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to compose in an initial step and want to use the results from this initial step in the following ones. If this is what you mean by

> ...is it possible to have a MEF compose in multiple steps? ...

you can look into this thread [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684766/is-it-possible-to-inject-an-existing-instance-into-a-mef-plugin) and continue with the MSDN for [CompositionBatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.compositionbatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Otherwise if your object tree can be initialized anytime, you can just call [Container.GetExportedValue()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd779656%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the type you need in your process.

Comment: Not sure if this is the same. Let say I have a class I want to compose using MEF called FooClass. FooClass has four imports - it imports FNeeded1, FNeeded2, FNeeded3 and FNeeded4, all are mandatory for Foo to work properly.

In Composing Step 1 I only can add FNeeded1 and FNeeded2 and want to start composition. Foo now works patialy. Later on, e.g. User Context gets available and I have now FNeeded3 and FNeeded 4. Now I want to finalize the composition of Foo.